# Find whether $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\,\dfrac{\cos nx}{2^n}$ is convergent by testing it for Cauchy convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I need to show that for any number $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive number $N_0 = N(\epsilon)$, that for any $n > N_0$ and for any $p$, $\:\biggl|\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\dfrac{\cos\,kx}{2^k}\biggr| \leq \epsilon$. So I did this: $$\biggl|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\,\dfrac{\cos kx}{2^k}\biggr| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\,\dfrac{1}{2^k} \leq \dfrac{p}{2^{n+1}},$$ but I don't actually understand how should I check if $\dfrac{p}{2^{n+1}} < \epsilon$, because I can pick an infinitely big number $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+p} \frac 1 {2^{k}} <\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{k}} =\frac1 {2^{n}}$.